# What are the rules of thumb for interpreting correlation coefficients corrected for unreliability?

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis, reliability, measurement-error, reliability-meta-analysis

I performed a series of meta-analyses in which we corrected correlation coefficients for measurement unreliability. A reviewer is asking us to define the magnitude of the meta-analytically-produced disattenuated validity coefficient (given as ρ). I was operating under the assumption that these rules of thumb were the same as those for Pearson's correlation coefficient (.10 = weak/small association; .30 = moderate correlation; .50+ = strong/large correlation). However, I am struggling to find a citation for this claim. So:

- what are the rules of thumb for interpreting disattenuated validity coefficients (ρ)?
- can you provide a citation for these rules?